# How to make conditional dropdown in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i am fresher in wordpress.
i am making relation dropdown in wordpress.
i want to make dropdown when parent dropdown option selected then in child dropdown show options relate to parent dropdown options and when child dropdown of option selected then sub child dropdown open.
how can i make table of parent,child,sub-child dropdown list in database of wordpress.

i am using contact form 7 plugin but not working
that dropdown also have checkboxs can select more then one options.

```
[select* my-name "-- choose -- " "option1" "option2"]
```

what is the process to make cascading dropdown in wordpress.  if any custom code or plugin in wordpress then suggest me to do this work.

Comment: Did you know there is a conditional field plugin with contact form 7 ? https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/  If you want to use cf 7 (for whatever reason), with this plugin you can show fields if a specific checkbox is checked, etc.

Comment: its good but i want three dropdown of checkbox which related to each other Example-i select product category i can select more then one category then automatically next subcategory1 dropdown show result according to category then next subcategory2 dropdown show result, its not necessary i use contact form 7 if you recommend any custom code or plugin then suggest me.

Comment: I think you have to use javascript to make it work. Personally would not suggest contact form 7 because that is not a meant use case. Maybe this fiddle can help? https://jsfiddle.net/o01y4x2y/4/ If not, you should try to make some code work, and if having trouble put this code in here and ask for help again.